# Pop back to previous ViewController not working on Alert Error Message

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have an alert that pops up when a user has not entered all their details correctly. I want it to pop back to the previous ViewController when the user dismisses the alert.

It looks something like this

```
func errorAlert (errorMessage: String?) {
    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Error message", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    popThisView()
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}

func popThisView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

but XCode gives me this error:

> popToViewController:transition: called on 
>   while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the
>   navigation stack will not be updated.

Comment: You need to add popToRootViewController in handler of Ok alert action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Error message", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler:{ (alertOKAction) in
                self.popThisView()
            }))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertAction object has a action handler, so you can handle action in that handler:

```
let action =  UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: . cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                self.popThisView()
            })
        })
```